# Invalid data after declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, kivy

I am trying to make a sort of personal vocabulary journal, I am new to python and kivy. My code is giving an error, i have checked it several times but still not working.It says invalid data after declaration I have checked for any possible error(which i know). I would appreciate any kind of help.
here is my code-

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup   
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

import json

Builder.load_file('VocabularyJournal.kv')

class MenuPage(Screen, StackLayout):
    pass

class WordInsertPage(Screen,FloatLayout):
    pass

class NewWordPage(Screen,StackLayout):
    word_box = ObjectProperty()
    meaning_box = ObjectProperty()
    Synonym_box = ObjectProperty()
    Ant_box = ObjectProperty()
    sentence_box = ObjectProperty()
    def input_data(self):
        data={}

        m=self.word_box.text
        data[m]={}
        data[m]['meaning']=self.meaning_box.text
        data[m]['synonym']=self.Synonym_box.text
        data[m]['antonym']=self.Ant_box.text
        data[m]['sentence']=self.sentence_box.text

    def saving_data(self):
        with open('vocab_new_word_page.txt','w') as of:
        json.dump(data,of)


class FlashCard(Screen):
    pass

class WordGroups(Screen):
    pass

sm=ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuPage(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(WordInsertPage(name='insertword'))
sm.add_widget(NewWordPage(name='newword')) 
sm.add_widget(FlashCard(name='flashcard'))
sm.add_widget(WordGroups(name='wordgroup'))

class VocabularyJournalApp(App):
    def build(self):
    return sm

object = VocabularyJournalApp()
object.run()
```

and here is the kv file-

```
<MenuPage>:
     Label: 
         text: "Vocabulary Journal"
         size_hint: .90,.10

     StackLayout:
         orientation: 'tb-rl'
         spacing: 10
         padding: 10

         Button:
             text: 'Search'
             size_hint: None,.20
             width: 130
             background_down:'darkgrey.png'
             on_press: root.manager.current='insertword'
         Button:
             text: 'New Word'
             size_hint: None,.20
             width: 130
             background_down:'darkgrey.png'
             on_press: root.manager.current='insertword'
         Button:
             text: 'Flash Cards'
             size_hint: None,.20
             width: 130
             background_down:'darkgrey.png'
             on_press: root.manager.current='flashcard'

         Button:
             text: 'Word Groups'
             size_hint: None,.20
             width: 130
             background_down:'darkgrey.png'
             on_press: root.manager.current='wordgroup'

<WordInsertPage>:
    FloatLayout:

        Button: 
            text: "New Word"
            on_press: root.manager.current='newword'
            font_size: 30
            color: 1,0,1,1
            size_hint: .3, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.5}
            background_down: 'darkgrey.png'
<NewWordPage>:
    id: refer_to_it
    StackLayout:
        orientation: 'tb-rl'
        spacing: 10
        word_box: word_input
        meaning_box: meaning_input
        Synonym_box: Synonym_input
        Ant_box: ant_input
        sentence_box: sentence_input
        padding: 90
        TextInput:
            text: "write your word here"
            color: 1,1,1,1
            id: word_input
            width: 300
            size_hint: None, .10

        TextInput:
            text: "write meaning of your word here"
            color: 1,1,1,1
            id: meaning_input
            width: 600
            size_hint: None, .20

        TextInput:
            text: "write Synonyms of your word here"
            color: 1,1,1,1
            id: Synonym_input
            width: 600
            size_hint: None, .20

        TextInput:
            text: "write antonyms of your text here"
            color: 1,1,1,1
            id: ant_input
            width: 600
            size_hint: None, .20

        TextInput:
            text: "write a sentence based on your word here"
            color: 1,1,1,1
            id: sentence_input
            width: 600
            size_hint: None, .20

        Button:
            text: 'Save'
            size_hint: None,.10
            width: 130
            background_down:'darkgrey.png'
            on_press: refer_to_it.saving_data
```

here is the error -

```
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\HP\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-
    02-25_5.txt
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0 
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) 
    [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif 
    (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "E:\SharanyaPy\desktop vocabulary journal\vocabJournal.py", 
            line 15, in <module>
             Builder.load_file('VocabularyJournal.kv')
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
            32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in 
            load_file
            return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
               32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 350, in 
             load_string
              parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
             32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 392, in 
             __init__
             self.parse(content)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
             32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 501, in parse
                objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
             32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 605, in 
             parse_level
             level + 1, lines[i:], spaces) 
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
              32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 605, in 
              parse_level
              level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
              32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 575, in 
              parse_level
            'Invalid data after declaration')
            kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File 
           "E:\SharanyaPy\desktop vocabulary journal\VocabularyJournal.kv", 
            line 55:
             ...
             53:        word_box: word_input
             54:        meaning_box: meaning_input
        >>   55:        Synonym_box: Synonym_input
             56:        Ant_box: ant_input
             57:        sentence_box: sentence_input
             ...
             Invalid data after declaration
```

I have checked the indentation,typos any other mistake that i know of, but it is still not working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code):

> Widget names should start with upper case letters while property names should start with lower case ones. Following the PEP8 Naming Conventions is encouraged.

So in your case the solution is to change the first letter of the properties to lowercase:

**.py**

```
synonym_box = ObjectProperty()
ant_box = ObjectProperty()
```

**.kv**

```
meaning_box: meaning_input
synonym_box: Synonym_input
```